# How can i move my installed apps in SD card on Sony Xperia Ray

Tags: internal-storage, app2sd, insufficient-memory, sony-xperia-ray

I can't install new apps, it says that my phone memory is running low. And I can't move my apps on SD card.

I also want to uninstall unnecessary apps on my phone but its says that "this can't be uninstalled". How to uninstall it?
[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: I've just added two more tags to your question. Their tag-wikis ([app2sd](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) and [insufficient-memory](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)) provide some first aid hints you could try. Note that to be moved via App2SD the app itself must support that. As for the not uninstallable apps: those are most likely pre-installed apps which are marked such. Without root there's nothing you can do to uninstall them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [this blog post](http://www.howtogeek.com/114667/how-to-install-android-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-move-almost-any-app-to-the-sd-card/).

There's a bit of coding/tweaking involved, but you don't need root for it.

To summarize, you need to run this inside `plat_form-tools` folders, command prompt

> $ adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2

Here's [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yebVRWKFug), if you prefer that.

Comment: btw, I just did this a few mins ago with my Samsung ACE :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you can't move those files to the SD card.  Maybe the sd card is full?  But to uninstall apps you can't the normal way I use [HiUninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hidroid.uninstaller). It requires root but it let's you uninstall any app and back it up in case you want it back.  Just be careful what you uninstall with it. You can find it on the market.

Comment: Please provide a link to the app.

Comment: Yup, sure, here it [is](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hidroid.uninstaller). Don't worry about the description being in Chinese. You have English in the app.

Comment: I added the link to your answer to facilitate easier reference for the users. Please do so yourself in your future answers. :)